# Center Align Content

Tags: html, alignment

I have the following two column layout setup on my webpage:

```
<div id="column1-wrap">
    <div id="column1">Column one content</div>
</div>
<div id="column2">
    Column two content
</div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
```

Which is powered by the following CSS:

```
#column1-wrap {
    float: left;
    width: 1000px;}
#column1 {
    margin-right: 600px;}
#column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: -600px;}
```

How can I center this on my webpage?

Comment: `margin:0 auto;width:90%;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bLr5S/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probaly are going for this:
**html**

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="column1-wrap">
     <div id="column1">Column one content</div>
   </div>
   <div id="column2">
      Column two content
   </div>
</div><!--container-->
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin:0px auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try adding

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to #column1-wrap in the css

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` only works when a width has been defined to an element

Comment: @Cruelcrome Just noticed that. My bad

Answer (score 2):

hi Div has a Property align to center the content

```
<div align:center>
</div>
```

or 
put style as `margin:0px auto;`

Comment: Do NOT do this. Inline styling is not considered good practice and aligning should be done in CSS. Plus, the syntax is wrong too.